# How to create an empty 2d array and assign values to it in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have created an empty 2d array:

```
multiArray = array(array());
```

I wanted to add items to the 2d array using a `foreach` statement, such that for each item, add all the items of a second array that correlate to it. This would build my 2d array. I am going about it as such:

```
# The following variables are prepopulated with items 
# $array1, my first array of items
# $array2, my second array of items

foreach ($array1 as $item1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $item2) {
        if ($item2['marker'] === $item1['marker'] { //item2 belongs to item 1 and thus needs to be added to the 2d array
            $mulitArray[][] = [$item1][$item2];
        }
    }
}
```

That is not working though logically it seems sounds, but the PHP doesn't like that `$mulitArray[][] = [$item1][$item2]`.

My expected output would be a 2d array that would show for each `item1`, all the `item2`s that match.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
$multiArray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $item1) {
    $a = array();
    foreach ($array2 as $item2) {
        if ($item1['marker'] == $item2['marker']) {
            $a[] = $item2;
        }
    }
    $multiArray[] = $a;
}
```

Comment: Yup, exactly what I needed. I didn't think to just create arrays instead of a counter. Thanks alot.

Comment: I feel this question could have some usefulness if reworded properly. Would you want to edit it for future use?